# How can I select a route change animation based on a method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this plunker that roughly demonstrates what I am intending to do. I'd like to select the kind of animation based on a method called. `pushPage()` would navigate and slide the entering page over the top - `popPage()` would slide the leaving page off the top.

https://plnkr.co/edit/atFX5SVUfpWAg6i2dXuM?p=preview

```
nav.pushPage(['angular', 'route'])
nav.popPage(['goes','here'])
```

I am just starting to learn how to use angular animations, any tips on how I could make this happen?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.